# How many ranged touch attacks can a Master Thrower do with the weak spot trick shot?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I'm playing as a Master Thrower who just attained the weak spot trick shot and I was wondering how often I could utilize the ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### There's no limit on how often weak spot can be used

A master thrower with the thrown weapon trick weak spot can use it as often as the master thrower likes.

Keep in mind, though, that the thrown weapon trick weak spot is only available to a level 5 master thrower, that the master thrower can use the thrown weapon trick weak spot only with weapons with which he has the feat Weapon Focus, that the target of the thrown weapon trick weak spot must be at least the master thrower's size category, and that the master thrower doesn't add his Strength bonus to the damage dealt when using the thrown weapon trick weak spot.

So while the thrown weapon trick weak spot is pretty cool for a halfling rogue that throws (somehow) drenched-in-contact-poison boomerangs or skiprocks, the trick's not usually as useful to a storm giant barbarian that hurls javelins.